# JavaScript error: Invalid Token when using ReCaptcha API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha

I have recently applied on my website an invisible Google ReCaptcha, but it is showing `Unexpected Error: Invalid token=` when I use the following code:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
    function onSubmit = function(token) {
       document.getElementById("admin-login").submit();
    }
</script>
```

I have a `form` `button` as follows:

```
<button data-sitekey="My Site Key" data-callback='onSubmit' class="btn btn-default submit g-recaptcha" name="login">Log in</button>
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: `var onSubmit = function...` not `function onSubmit = function...` if you want to create a variable that is a function. If you are just trying to define a function, `function onSubmit (token) { ...}` will suffice

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`function onSubmit = function(token) {` is incorrect.

It needs to be

`var onSubmit = function(token) {`

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<script>
    var onSubmit = function(token) {
    document.getElementById("admin-login").submit();
    }
</script>
```

JavaScript allows different ways to create a function. It would be better if you read through following in detail.

**1. Function Declaration**

`function onSubmit(){
    }`

**2. Function Expression**

`var onSubmit = function(){
    }`

**3. Arrow Functions**
    `([params]) => { //function Body }`

**4. Generator Functions** (More Advanced)
    `function* generatorFunction(){ yield 5; }`

Comment: @Webmaster Ask another question and post a link here and we'll take a look

Comment: @Webmaster, if you've got a different question you should post it as another question - please don't try to ask/answer separate questions in the comments, as that's not the place for it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is two ways to create/declare a function:

```
function onSubmit(token) {
    document.getElementById("admin-login").submit();
}
```

or

```
var onSubmit = function(token) {
    document.getElementById("admin-login").submit();
};
```

You kinda mixed the two.